# Need to identify between range of postal codes

Tags: regex, string, vba, range

I'm pretty new to [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and I'm trying to figure out how to identify a postal code that falls within a range where one character changes.

For example, I want to see if a postal code falls between `2G8` and `2P8`.

In other words, the range of what I'm looking for would be `2_8` where the *underscore* can be `G` to `P`, but I don't know how to identify that in code.

I'd really appreciate some help to figure out how to approach this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`LIKE` avoids repeated string testing

**1. Simple Test**

```
Function ValidString(strIn As String) As Boolean
ValidString = strIn Like "2[G-P]8"
End Function
```

**2. Case Insensitive version**

```
Function ValidString(strIn As String) As Boolean
ValidString = LCase$(strIn) Like LCase$("2[G-P]8")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked really easily.
Now, the main problem I'm having is that I have so many ranges that I have to filter through so I'd have to create a separate function for each one.

Comment: You could put the ranges in an array and loop through and check if any of them match.

Comment: @user960358 can you provide some examples of the ranges? I like mellamokb's array idea.

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of the VBA `Mid` function to pull out each character and validate it according to your business rules.  Here's an example of how it might look:

```
Function ValidatePostalCode(code As String)
    ValidatePostalCode = _
        (Mid(code, 1, 1) = "2") And _
        (Mid(code, 2, 1) >= "G" And Mid(code, 2, 1) <= "P") And _
        (Mid(code, 3, 1) = "8")
End Function
```

This Function will return a value of `True` or `False` indicating whether the input is valid.